# JQuery UI Drag & Drop And Align

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Here is my draggable and droppable implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/A26ww/

I have groups of playlists and I need to be able to drag a playlist from one group to another. I can do that however I would like to nicely position / align the dropped playlist. Right now it just stays in an awkward position after dropping.

Here is the problem:

[image]

I would like the dropped divto align nicely with other divs in the droppable container.

My code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        revert: "invalid"
    });

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            // TODO HELP ME
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Was my answer not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think [jQuery UI sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) is what you are looking for. I hope you can change your HTML markup.
Especially see the [connected lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists) possibility.

I updated your <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A26ww/9/)</kbd>.

```
$('.draggable, .droppable').sortable({
    connectWith: '.playlists'
});
```

Changing it to sortable requires a few changes but still I think this is easier to achieve with sortable than draggable/droppable.

Instead of `<div>` I used `<ul>` and `<li>` and styled them accordingly. (but there are some minor changes you have to do, so the styling looks exactly the same as with divs)

```
<div class="group">Group A
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul class="playlists droppable">
        <li class="playlist draggable">Playlist 0</li>
        <li class="playlist draggable">Playlist 1</li>
        <li class="playlist draggable">Playlist 2</li>
        <li class="playlist draggable">Playlist 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Referring to @R2D2's comment I added the `min-height` property, so even an empty list (`<ul>`) has enough height to accept a dropped element.

Comment: One thing, when you drag all elements from group B and drop them in group A (leaving group B empty), you can't drop any elements back to group B.

Comment: Seems like it didn't save my comment O.o However @R2D2 I updated my fiddle and added a short comment. Should work now :)